# How to use SQL to filter a column to simultaneously 'equal to something' and 'not equal to something else'?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, relational-database, toad

I have a table called `PM_BATCH_ST` like this:

| BATCH_ID | RESULT |
| --- | --- |
| 1000564932 | ISC |
| 1000564932 | LLC |
| 1000585739 | ISC |
| 1000585739 | LLC |
| 1000384769 | ISC |
| 1000384769 | LLC |
| 1000384757 | LLC |
| 1000888940 | ISC |

Can I filter the table to obtain `BATCH_ID`s that ONLY have an `ISC` entry? So the result I would like is just 1000888940.

I understand that I can filter it by

```
WHERE RESULT LIKE '%ISC%'
```

But that will also return 1000564932, 1000585739, 1000384769 which also have an entry for `LLC`.

Comment: ... that has the only value in a set is `having count(distinct column) = 1 and max(column) = 'ISC'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select like this

```sql
SELECT BATCH_ID
FROM PM_BATCH_ST
GROUP BATCH_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 AND MAX(RESULT) = 'ISC'
```

Unlike the WHERE clause the HAVING clause is exceuted on the grouped result. `COUNT(*) = 1` ensures there is only one result and `MAX(RESULT) = 'ISC'` ensures this reult is for a ISC. I took `MAX` because we need an aggregate function here, but since we have only one result `MIN` would work as well.

Comment: @ Olivier Jacot-Descombes
Thank you very much for this.

May I ask one more related point on this?

If I wanted to filter the table for just BATCH_IDs that have two ISC entries, (e.g. Let's say that for Batch 1000564932 above, that both entries for it say ISC, instead of one of them saying LLC), would I simply change  the '1' after COUNT(*) to '2' in the SQL Solution above that you provided?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `group by` and `having` clause :

```
select BATCH_ID
from mytable
group by BATCH_ID
having sum(case when RESULT = 'ISC' then 1 else 0 end) = count(*)
```

This will returns `BATCH ID`, where total rows must equal total rows with `RESULT = 'ISC'`.

To get `BATCH_ID` with only one `ISC` Entry then add count(*) = 1 to the `having` clause :

```
having sum(case when RESULT = 'ISC' then 1 else 0 end) = count(*) and count(*) = 1
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/nnMQmxhx)

Answer (score 0):

in the query we first filter all Batch_ids that have ISC in it and then count the occurences of all rows that have not ISC as result, mulitple ISC will be ignored

```
SELECT
"BATCH_ID"  FROM PM_BATCH_ST p1
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM PM_BATCH_ST WHERE p1."BATCH_ID" ="BATCH_ID" AND "RESULT" = 'ISC')
GROUP BY "BATCH_ID"
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN "RESULT" != 'ISC' THEN 1 ELSe 0 END ) = 0
```

| BATCH_ID |
| --- |
| 1000888940 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/aHYMOf8a)